# Display static map with VueLayers

Tags: vue.js, openlayers, vuelayers

I tried

`:controls="false"` on `vl-map`
The buttons disappear but you can still zoom with trackpad or mouse and move the map

then I tried setting `min-view` and `max-view` on `vl-view` but this has no effect on zoom

then I set the `extent` on `vl-view` and that partially works: I cannot move the map but can still zoom

How do you make the map completely static ?

Answer (score 0):

Though i'm not familiar with the Vue-library, Several of the interactions you mention are derived from the "interaction" module, and not the "controls" module. See for example:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_DragRotateAndZoom-DragRotateAndZoom.html

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_MouseWheelZoom-MouseWheelZoom.html

I would check if it's possible to remove these interactions the way you removed the controls. Alternatively you can call your map object and use removeInteraction(interaction):

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#removeInteraction